# What are the main difference between panels and paragraphs?

Tags: theming, 8, panels, paragraphs

What are the main difference between the [Panels](https://www.drupal.org/project/panels) and [Paragraphs](https://www.drupal.org/project/paragraphs) module in Drupal 8?

As far as I know both of the modules can be used for creating landing pages.

When to use paragraph and when to user panels?

Comment: I prefer Paragraphs for various reasons. UX, content management, performance, searchability (Solr etc)...

Comment: http://www.mediacurrent.com/blog/editorial-workflow-head-head-paragraphs-vs-entity-embed-vs-panelizer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They are not the same and you can't do the same thing with them.

[Panels](https://www.drupal.org/project/panels)

> The Panels module allows a site administrator to create customized
>   layouts for multiple uses.

[Paragraphs](https://www.drupal.org/project/paragraphs)

> Paragraphs module comes with a new "paragraphs" field type that works
>   like Entity Reference's.

With Paragraphs you can create collections of items, like you can do with [Field collection](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_collection), as they are fields that you can attach to your content types, you can't do this with Panels.

In the other hand if you want to modify your layout in a simple and easy way you can use Panels, and if you have a collection of items maybe you have used Paragraphs in the content that you're showing.